# relative imports between directories from the same package

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-import

I'm having some trouble with relative imports for the following situation.

I have a package, with two module directories, and I want to import a module from `dir_b` to a module from `dir_a`.

Here's an example of my package structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── builder
│   ├── build_moto.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── parts
    ├── car.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── moto.py
    └── truck.py
```

I'm trying to import `moto` inside `build_moto` using relative imports, like this:

```
$ cat builder/build_moto.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3

from .parts import moto
```

...but when I execute `build_moto.py`, it generates the following error:

```
$ python3 builder/build_moto.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "builder/build_moto.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .parts import moto
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I'd like to understand:

- why this configuration is not working?
- what must be done in order to perform a relative import for this case in specific?

Comment: [**Relative imports for the billionth time**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, this problem can be solved like this:

```
python3 -m builder.build_moto
```

The `-m` argument means that you are running your module as part of a library:

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Comment: Yes, that's a possible solution, but I need a different approach, like using relative imports. This example, is a representation of what I have from a part of a web application which I'm developing.

Comment: I don't understand. Perhaps you should consult the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: Thanks, @erewok :)! It helped me to understand a little bit more about my issue.